# FTP issue. Files are uploading but when going to them they don't show up

Tags: linux, wordpress, ubuntu

I'm new to linux and I'm attempting to setup a server on Linode. Using ubuntu and attempting to setup wordpress with a lot of snags. At the moment I setup a FTP server on this box and am able to login and view the files and upload. All that good stuff is working, but when I upload and index page and go to the server address in my browser it still has the default "It Works! The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet." page. Why is it not loading my index? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What web server are you running? Have you configured it yet?

Answer (score 2):

This almost always in the result of the files being uploaded to the wrong directory. Your files need to be placed in the webroot of your website. This folder can have several names including:

- htdocs
- www
- public_html
- httpdocs

Find that directory and place your files in there.

You may also need to delete the default home page as it may have priority over your new page and will continue to show until you delete it.